Science fiction book involving a female alien with biological augmentations who comes to Earth to conquer it for her species
The plot involved an alien that had inadvertently come to Earth.  The alien has many biological augmentations such as pheromones that humans can only weakly sense, but that feels like strong charisma.
The alien wants to conquer Earth as a re-wilded world for her species to enjoy, so she enlists the aid of a human environmentalist and begins reducing the human population via a virus.  A human from her universe arrives to fight her.  He has no augmentations but has machinery to make him as strong as her.
I recall one plot point where some humans attempt to rape the alien, thinking she's a weak human.  She kills all of them except one that she then rapes.  She puts spider thingies in his ear that turn him into a thrall for her. In the alien's world, the dominant species keeps another human species that act as domestics for them.
What is this book?  It's been driving me crazy lately trying to recall the author/name of the book.

In roughly which year did you read this?

Drakon by S. M. Stirling, from 1996.  The female character is from an Earth where "The Domination of the Draka" had genetically engineered themselves into a post-human form, and engineered the rest of humanity into "homo servus" - a servant species.
The plot involved an alien that had inadvertently come to Earth.

The book starts in 2442 A.D. somewhere in North America – thinly
inhabited and with scattered remnants of the Americans having been
quite literally bombed into the Stone Age – where Gwendolyn Ingolfson
is ending a camping and hunting trip. On her way back to the
civilization she contacts legate Tamirindus Rohm, who sends her to the
Reichart Station to oversee the creation of a wormhole generator.
During a test of the generator an error occurs and before she can get
clear she is caught by the wormhole and is sent to an alternate Earth,
called Earth/2.

The alien has many biological augmentations such as pheromones that
humans can only weakly sense, but that feels like strong charisma.
From this site:

Draka also generate pheromones that cause humans to react to them
favorably. Draka can consciously adjust the intensity of these
pheromones, ranging from a subtle positive disposition to inducing
overwhelming lust. Prolonged exposure to Draka pheromones will
essentially brainwash any ordinary human into a loyal follower.

A human from her universe arrives to fight her. He has no augmentations but has machinery to make him as strong as her.

During the same time Kenneth Lafarge comes to Earth/2, ending up in a
cornfield somewhere in Illinois. He starts with trying to contact the
CIA, explaining why he is there and who Gwendolyn is, but everyone
thinks he is insane and he is forced to fight his way out.

The alien wants to conquer Earth as a re-wilded world for her species to enjoy, so she enlists the aid of a human environmentalist and begins reducing the human population via a virus.
From the book itself
Seducing the environmentalist:

Gwen leaned forward, fixing his eyes with hers. “Imagine a world,” she
said softly, almost whispering, forcing him to lean closer to hear,
“where the population of Earth is five hundred million and stable, not
seven billion and rising. Where not an ounce of fossil fuel is burned.
No mines, no factories, no fission reactors or coal-burning plants, no
tankers full of oil. The sea and the skies and the land swarm with
life, and whole continents are nature preserves.”

Being non-human
Gwen replied. “I’m not human.”

His head came up. “You could have fooled me.”
“I couldn’t fool a CAT scan or DNA analysis. Post-human; genetically
modified, to about a six percent divergence. Homo drakensis, to be
precise. Most of it doesn’t show, but I’m as different from you as an
orangutan.”

